# WP - How to constantly update my location

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone, mvvm-light

Currently my location not updating when I change it to different location via emulator. But it will change after I restart my application. This is what I write when the app launch

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings Settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        GeoCoordinate DefaultLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-6.595139, 106.793801);
        Library.GPSServices MyGPS;

        if (!Settings.Contains("FirstLaunch") || (bool)Settings["FirstLaunch"] == true)
        {
            Settings["FirstLaunch"] = false;
            Settings["LastLocation"] = DefaultLocation;
            Settings["SearchRadius"] = 1;
        }

        //If key not exist OR key value was set to false, ask for permission to use location
        if (!Settings.Contains("LocationService") || (bool)Settings["LocationService"] == false)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Jendela Bogor need to know your location to work correctly, do you want to allow it?",
                "Allow access to your location?",
                MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                Settings["LocationService"] = true;
                MyGPS = new Library.GPSServices();
            }
            else
            {
                Settings["LocationService"] = false;
            }

            Settings.Save();
        }

        else if ((bool)Settings["LocationService"] == true)
        {
            MyGPS = new Library.GPSServices();
        }
    }
```

I store my location in my application setting `IsolatedStorage` with name `Settings["LastLocation"]`

How should I do to constantly update my location in the Background using MVVM Pattern (MVVM-Light) so my `PushPin` on map in the ThirdPageView always updated?

**EDIT**

```
   public GPSServices()
    {
        if ((bool)Settings["LocationService"] == true)
        {          
            if (_watcher == null)
            {
                _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                _watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;
            }

            StartWatcher();

            _watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
            _watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        }
        else if ((bool)Settings["LocationService"] == false)
        {
            StopWatcher();
        }
    }

    private void StartWatcher()
    {
        _watcher.Start();
    }

    private void StopWatcher()
    {
        if (_watcher != null)
            _watcher.Stop();
    }

    private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (e.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please wait while your position is determined....");
            return;
        }

        Settings["LastLocation"] = e.Position.Location;
        Settings.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher` provides what you need.

```cs
var geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
// This event fires every time the device location changes
geoWatcher.PositionChanged += (s, e) => {  
    //e.Position.Location will contain the current GeoCoordinate
};

geoWatcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
```

Comment: My `GPSServices` class containing all of it, see my post that I've edit. And still no luck.

Comment: I don't see you updating any map controls in watcher_PositionChanged. You only seem to be saving the new location to settings. You need to plot the new position on your map. Does your GPSService class has any methods to plot a position on map?

Comment: I've solve this by looking this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568581/how-do-i-move-gps-watcher-to-app-xaml-superclass-and-dispatch-events-to-other-pa), I instantiate my GPSService at `App` class. But, I dont know what and how to use Dispatcher. Maybe by using Dispatcher, I can update the new position on my map?

Comment: Dispatcher is used to execute code on the UI thread, it has nothing to do with updating maps. If you have access to the map control variable you can plot the updated locations right inside PositionChanged method.

Comment: I bind my push pin from the ViewModel, how do I update this property from GPSService class?

Answer (score 0):

*is this helpful for you ? using GeocoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged event?*

```
public Location()
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher location == new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        location.PositionChanged += new  EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(location_PositionChanged);
        location.Start();
    }


    //event to track the location change
    public void location_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {

    }
```